# How does Kong detect connection timeout?

Tags: lua, api-gateway, kong, kong-plugin, kong-ingress

Currently, whenever an upstream service is down, kong will throw
"{"message":"failure to get a peer from the ring-balancer"}"

I am trying to create a custom plugin that detects the connection time out and return a customized message to the client, the blocker I am facing right now is writing lua codes in my custom plugin to detect the timeout. I have tried using

```
if(kong.response.get_source() == "error")
```

but that does not seem to detect timeout either.

Does anyone have any idea what I should do to detect connection timeout in when writing a custom kong plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I didn't catch you. Because I don't know what your function will return

If `kong.response.get_source()` returns a string `{"message":"failure to get a peer from the ring-balancer"}`

You need to use the JSON library to parse it.

```
local json = require("json")
local res = json.deceode(kong.response.get_source())
if res.message == "xxx" then

end
```

But your `message` is a little long. You can add a new key-value to the JSON string to represent the state.

For example:`"{"status":"error","message":"failure to get a peer from the ring-balancer"}"`

Then you can write code like this.

```
local json = require("json")
local res = json.deceode(kong.response.get_source())
if res.status == "error" then

end
```

---

I just looked at the [Kong API Docs](https://docs.konghq.com/gateway-oss/2.0.x/pdk/kong.response/).

I find that the return value of `kong.response.get_source()` is HTTP status code, such as 200/500.

You can try `print(kong.response.get_source())` and see the results.

Comment: Hi @MushroomMogu,
The "{"message":"failure to get a peer from the ring-balancer"}" response I'm getting is not from any function I wrote, Idk where its from either, what I'm trying to do is intercept that message from from being shown to client, which is why I created a custom plugin.
In the plugin, I used if(kong.response.get_source() == "error"), according to https://docs.konghq.com/gateway-oss/2.4.x/pdk/kong.response/#kongresponseget_source, it is supposed to catch errors while processing request, eg: timeout while connecting to the upstream service. But that doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: @Serene Did you get any solution for this?